# Get sourcecode into Jenkins WORKSPACE subdirectory

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

Is it possible to configure Jenkins to get source code into a subdirectory of a `%WORKSPACE%`? Right now the source gets pulled into `%WORKSPACE%` and for the build output I explicitly specify a directory outside of the `%WORKSPACE%`.

Ideally I would like to have something similar to this:

`%WORKSPACE%\source` for source code and `%WORKSPACE%\artifacts` for build outputs. Is it possible to have this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'run batch command' build step and use xcopy, this is presuming jenkins is running on a Windows machine, if it's a deployment directory then make it a post build step.

```
cd c:/
xcopy /Y "c:/program files 86/junkies/workspace/app" "c:/path to new directory"
```

This is just a guess at your directories, replace with correct ones, the /Y forces it to be overwritten every time it's copied.